# pgfplot domain with defined step size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am currently trying to display a sine wave, but can't seem to show it using the right steps size.

Is it possible in `pgfplots` to determine the steps size of where the data points should be placed..

So for instance if I have an audio signal which was sampled with 8000 hz.

Each sample should be plotted given these specifications

```
   %% Time specifications:
   Fs = 8000;                   % samples per second
   dt = 1/Fs;                   % seconds per sample
   StopTime = 0.03;             % seconds
   t = (0:dt:StopTime-dt)';     % seconds
```

But from what i can does `pgfplot` an option where i can a `dt`..

My current plot...

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \addplot[samples=240,domain=0:1] {
        cos(2*3.14*60*x)+cos(2*3.14*60*5*x)+sin(2*3.14*60*10*x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

question condensed: Is there someway I can incorporate the time specification specified above in the `pgfplot`.

Comment: Take a look at the pgfplots keys `samples=<num>`, `domain=<interval>` and (maybe) `samples at=<list>`. Also this goes without saying, but it would be useful for potential answerers if you provided a working example (written in actual code).

Comment: your "step size" is determined by number of samples ...

Comment: ohh.. ahh cool :)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @JohnKormylo adding 180/pi seem to be the easiest solution..

Comment: BTW, sin()_ and cos() use degrees, so multiplying by 2*3.14 is probably not a good idea.  In addition, pi is a recognized constant, and every intermediate calculation will be repeated over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John's comment hints you may actually want the following

Also, a more simple way of doing, I think....

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      [
        %axis lines = center,
        xmin=0,
        domain=0:.03,
        samples=201 % I find 101 is enough in print, 201 is better on screen
      ]
      \addplot [blue] {cos(deg(60*x))+cos(deg(60*5*x))+sin(deg(60*10*x))};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Orig

This seems to do the trick.

(I tried to remain faithful to the style of your setup)

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
  \def\Fs{8000}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\dt}{1/\Fs}
  \def\StopTime{.03}
  \def\samplesAt{0,\dt,...,\StopTime-\dt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
        \addplot[samples at=\samplesAt] 
          {cos(2*3.14*60*x)+cos(2*3.14*60*5*x)+sin(2*3.14*60*10*x)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```